# Function component doesn't re-render after updating array state in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to make a little react application that saves short text entries. The app shows all published entries and the user can add a new entry by writing and publishing it.

The applcation has an `string-array (string[])` type. Every item in the array is an entry that has to be displayed in the frontend entries list.

I know that I can't `push` to the array because that doesn't changes the state directly (and react doesn't notice that it have to be re-rendered). So i am using this way to get the new state: `oldState.concat(newEntry)`. But React doesn't re-render it.

Here is my whole react code:

```js
function App() {
    const [entries, setEntries] = useState([] as string[])

    const publish = (entry: string) => {
        setEntries(entries.concat(entry))
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Entries entries={entries} />
            <EntryInput publish={publish} />
        </div>
    )
}

function Entries(props: { entries: string[] }) {
    return (
        <div className="entries">
            {props.entries.map((v, i) => { <EntryDisplay msg={v} key={i} /> })}
        </div>
    )
}

function EntryInput(props: { publish: (msg: string) => void }) {
    return (
        <div className="entry-input">
            <textarea placeholder="Write new entry..." id="input-new-entry" />
            <button onClick={(e) => { props.publish((document.getElementById("input-new-entry") as HTMLTextAreaElement).value) }}>Publish</button>
        </div>
    )
}

function EntryDisplay(props: { msg: string }) {
    return (
        <div className="entry">{props.msg}</div>
    )
}

const reactRoot = document.getElementById("react-root")
ReactDOM.render(<App />, reactRoot)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State is updated correctly, the return keyword is missing here:

```
function Entries(props: { entries: string[] }) {
    return (
        <div className="entries">
            {props.entries.map((v, i) => {
                // add missing 'return'
                return <EntryDisplay msg={v} key={v} />
            })}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Also, don't use array [indexes as keys.](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#targetText=We%20don't%20recommend%20using,cause%20issues%20with%20component%20state.)